# Format (4 spaces) all code files in Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio, code-formatting

I was working on an old branch `feature/old-request`, that branch did not have the `.editorconfig` file that informs Visual Studio to use 4 spaces (company agreed formatting).

So on my old branch, Visual Studio was using my own personal settings (2 spaces). Now that I am trying to merge branches (`develop` into `feature/old-request`), I'm getting a lot of changed files and the only change is the spacing.

I have now aborted the merge, then taken the same `.editorconfig` file from the `develop` branch and put it on my `feature/old-request` branch.

I don't fancy opening 100s of files and pressing `Ctrl` + `K` `Ctrol` + `D`.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to format all code files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is excellent tool in dotnet CLI for this: [dotnet-format](https://github.com/dotnet/format)

It is also available for installation directly from command line:

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-format
```

Now, when you have your catalog with solution setup like this:

```
path to solution catalog
-- ConsoleApp
-- .editorconfig
-- ConsoleApp.sln
```

(this is just sample solution for example purposes).

Now, run command `dotnet-foramt` in solution directory and it will automatically apply settings from `.editorconfig` to your solution.